# Get search text and apply keyup listener to the search textbox - Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.js to display a list of options with the search text box for auto-completion. I need to attach a keyup event listener to the search text box and do some processing on the search keywords entered.

I have tried

```
$('#searchTxt .search-field input').keyup(function(e){alert("This works.");});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: This won't do anything because your `.keyup` callback (`function(e){}`) is empty. Are you actually doing anything inside that function? If so, please post some code in your question.

Comment: Yes, i had an alert statement inside the function to check if the method is getting invoked. In essence, i need to access the input text box which is inside a div class and attach a keyup listener.

Comment: Make working fiddle of your problem and let us know